# Exception in thread main - maven dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

```
public class BatchLauncherSpring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "application-context.xml");

        //////
    }
}
```

I'm getting ClassNotFoundException when I run the main method. The Spring dependencies are added through Maven and these dependencies are resolved at compile time. There are lot of similar questions out there but everyone seems to be having an issue when the code is packaged as jar and executed outside of eclipse. I'm actually getting this issue when I run it in eclipse itself.

This is the pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatch</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatchCore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mybatchCore</name>
    <url></url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.repo</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.repo</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.repo</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.repo</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.repo</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

stacktrace

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>   Exception in thread "main"

What is the issue here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the stacktrace please?

Comment: Why are you using `com.my.repo` as grouId to obtain the Spring libraries rather than the official groupId `org.springframework`?

Comment: do you have the spring-context dependency!?

Comment: @DirkLachowski - added stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the spring-context dependency
happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Without a stacktrace, we can only guess, but the first thing that pops out to me is you using this for the groupId for the spring dependencies: `com.my.repo`. That should be `org.springframework`.

I'm not sure how this is even compiling.

Comment: Our company has own repo. We are not supposed to use the default Maven groupId

Comment: @RKodakandla then don't raise a question here but at your company coworkers. And even more, I would raise questions to the person or people in charge of this !@#$%& design.

Comment: his probably using an internal repo thats a snapshot of the maven repo

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza dude from your comment I would say Ur a home coder, companies usually use their own repos,, since they can push their third party jars and stuff which is available for the hole team, do ur research ;)

Comment: also if ur boss tells u to code something, and you get stuck usually u don't go to the boss and say hey how is this done,

Comment: @MRK187 in the team I work, we help each other. If in your team everybody lives in an isle, then good for you. And again, if you have a problem in your environment, the first thing I'll do is to ask to a coworker or review how other people in the company have solved similar problems. Do your research about teamwork ;)

Comment: Im not getting in a discussion with you, but seems stupid to use maven repo directly in a company, since their is no way to push third-party dependencies, or for that sake your teams/company jars, not to mention the liability

Comment: @MRK187 even if a company uses its own repository, why would you waste your time redeploying the artifacts with your own groupId, which gets you no benefit except wasting your time? In my company we use our own repo, but use the standard artifact and group id (because the company repository is configured as proxy to Maven central, which is the right way, except when you have to obey some fancy legal stuff, where every JAR has to be approved itself etc. etc.).

Comment: I don't know, why that's confusing, that's the way Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva etc. works.

Comment: @dunni Isn't this is a design matter, in some companies it's preferable to be able to see the internal repo and maven repo as one, since i would prefer as a developer not knowing how this works in the background. But how would you solve this situation: you have someApp.1.1.jar in the Maven repo. Somewhere along your team notice they will need the 2.0 version of that jar, and it is not in the maven repo, luckily someone in your team has pushed that version to your repo, would you then prefer it to be named the groupId spring.frameworks, or would you name it my.groups.framework,

Comment: how would you seperate those?

Comment: If it is an open source library, then i would use the "official" groupId. Also, with a repository manager, you as developer only point to one repository URL (in Nexus it's called "group"), and in that group all external and internal repositories are combined. So as developer, you have one URL where you get all Maven artifacts you need, and as administrator of the repo manager, you still can have multiple repositories (to separate by project for example).

Comment: If you're interested, we can move the discussion into the chat

Comment: That actually sounds interesting I am pretty new too spring, and I am actually pushing to introduce this in our structure, I'll read up on that first, allthough I would appreciate getting some help on this question instead which is regarded with spring as well :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/30378061/2323234