# Explicit type conversion between child spring object, and it's super java.util object

Tags: java, spring, casting, jms, jdbctemplate

In spring I am using jdbcTemplate, but having a problem that it is returning a Linkedcaseinsensitivemap when querying for a List, when doing the following I still get the spring linkedcaseinsensitivemap, even if I cast it to java util List and define the left-side of the assignment as a java.util.List.

Firstly how is that even possible?

```
final java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> list = (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>) jdbc
          .queryForList("SELECT * FROM customer");
```

so, how would one achive doing this type of upcaste? 
without needing to declare a second list allocate memory for it and then put the objects manually into the java.util.List?

Since the LinkedCaseInsensitive is subclassing the java object, Im having a hard time figuring out how to cast to the super object which is the java List. How to achieve this is a mystery at the moment.

since there is no way currently to know which brokers will use our AMQ, the goal is too strictly keep to jms objects, 
So I can't start sending spring objects, since jms should be our standard, also please note I do not have the option to implement the AMQProtocol, I need to send basic java objects,

Since serialising to JSON has been suggested I will explain why it does not work in this case, why I'll need to send the Objects "as-are" to the receiver since they will put it into a Notes document.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= metadata.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                String columnName = metadata.getColumnName(i);
                Object values = sqlConnection.getRset().getObject(i);
                doc.replaceItemValue(columnName, values);

}
```

So SO'ers, how does one achieve doing this more beautifully?
please help
thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the problem with sending LinkedCaseInsensitivemap using interface List, does that cause any problem? Do you want to make it case-sensitive? it that the problem?

Comment: cant expect the reciever to use spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

A SQL select can return multiple rows, and each row has multiple selected columns.
The [queryForList method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-) you are calling returns a List with for each selected row a Map mapping column name to column value.

Map and List are interfaces, so Spring is free to pick whatever implementation it likes. It chooses the LinkedCaseInsensitiveHashMap for the Map because that map will list the keys in the order of insertion. So the order in which the columns were selected does not get lost.

If you wish to send the result list to a receiver that you know little about, you can probably best serialize it to JSON and send it as a text message.

You can serialize to JSON using a library like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome). You create  a serializer and feed it the object you wish to convert to a String.
So for example in Gson, where the serializer class is called Gson:

```
TextMessage message;
// initialize message and headers however you like
// then serialize it to String:
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(list);
// and set it in the message:
message.setText(json);
```

(You can also let Spring JmsTemplate do this for you using a MessageConverter that converts to JSON but I'd estimate that that's a bit harder to get working.)

Alternatively, if you wish to customize the Map that you send as an ObjectMessage, you can use [a different query method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) that allows you to specify a custom [RowMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) that creates a java.util.Map implementation of your liking. Note that if you use a TreeMap, it'll sort the columns alphabetically and if you use a HashMap, it'll put them in random order.

The receiver then can unpack the JSON back into Java objects. gson.fromGson(json) will return a List of Maps.

Comment: Yes that is an obvious choice, but in this case since the MQ is handling more then just resultsets, it will be more desirable to send resultsets as an object which is parsed on the receiving end. While sending other information in plain text., i.e. The type of objects sent will be handled differently, reciever will know in this way tha an objectMessage contains resultsets, while textEssages contain other information like error or status etc.. Also I feel a very large text message will be hard to handle than an List<map<>>, with a map per row.

Comment: just curious how would the reciever know what "type" of message it has recieved? would you solve that with a prefix of some sort in each message?

Comment: You can provide headers in a JMS message that explain what the contents of the message are. You can also send messages of different types to different destinations, though then messages of a different type may get processed out of order from each other.

Comment: oyeah thats right the type can be set in the header, you know what Im starting to see the value in just sending text for everything. Can you explain what you mean by serilize it to json? you mean I should change the list for a Serializable and the put that into a json? create a jms message specify the header in jms for the type like "resultset" then just add the json to it? our am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I've added an example of how to convert the list of maps to JSON.

Comment: Only problem I see with this is that we loose the actual object, and only send text, Is there anyway to keep the actual DB Object types, or is the easiest way to send just the List with the objects "as-are", see my example in question

Comment: The receiver then can unpack the JSON back into Java objects. gson.fromGson(json) will return a List of Maps.

Comment: but.. there is always a but.. sql Date is transformed to string, so its not really working as thought, ill just go with my own answer until further...

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I've figured out how to have a child object to become it's parent class without breaking out into methods - in my described scenario doing the following:

```
final java.util.ArrayList<java.util.Map<String, Object>> javaList = new java.util.ArrayList<java.util.Map<String, Object>>();
        final java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Object>> list = jdbc
                  .queryForList("SELECT * FROM customer");
        javaList.addAll(list);
```

But doesn't look good to me, how would one achive this in a more right way?

Comment: You're copying the original list's contents to an ArrayList but the contents will still be the spring-specific linked hashmaps.

Comment: No it will not, this has been tested with the desired results.

Comment: You're not changing any Maps, simply copying their references to an ArrayList.

Comment: AddAll method addAll(Collection<? extends E> c). Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: You're saying that it's the Map implementation that's nonstandard and then you're copying these nonstandard Maps from the returned ArrayList to a newly created ArrayList. That means only the List will be different, not the Maps in it.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out ive cleared that up, guess it's to late in the evening..

Comment: but I am pretty sure you are wrong that the map is not a java map http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-

Comment: It's an implementation of the standard java interface java.util.Map. The implementing class is org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap which is spring-specific.

Comment: no dude you are wrong about that, did you even look at the link? try pressing the Map it directs you to java Map http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true its only the outer List which is Spring specifik

Comment: The outer list is a java.util.ArrayList, which implements the interface java.util.List. The inner Maps are [org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.html)s which implement the interface java.util.Map.

Comment: -.- its seem to be right what you are saying, but still its just beating round the bush, I'm in which case getting a spring object inplace where I need java objects... please note I'm on my phone,,

Comment: I need to cast up whatever object spring has made up to their parent java objects, how do I go about doing that? please don't regard the details I couldnt care less what is and is not spring in the return, as long as its not spring, keep to the problem